# Change div layout after media query snap

Tags: html, css

I have created a demo of an article post and layout for a page of a website I am creating. I am happy with the layout for the desktop view and tablet view but for mobile I need to later the layout slightly.

Here is a demo to see the changes at the three breakpoints:

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamdanbarrett/cpLvcydL/)

Focusing on the mobile view, I need the following:

Post title and post body to be at the top of the div with the post menu still on the right.

Post avatar sat underneath the post body content spread across the same width.

I cannot get this to work, are there any suggestions?

Here is the html layout:

```
    <aside class="timeline_main_nav">

        <nav>
            Timeline Menu
        </nav>

    </aside>

    <section class="timeline_body">

        <article class="timeline_posts">

            <div class="timeline_post_body">

                <div class="timeline_post_avatar">Avatar</div>
                <div class="timeline_post_menu">Post menu</div>
                <div class="timeline_post_title">Post Title</div>
                <div class="timeline_post_body">Post Body</div>
                <div class="timeline_post_footer">Post Footer</div>

            </div>

        </article>

    </section>

    <aside class="timeline_ads">

        <div>
            Timeline AdSpace
        </div>

    </aside>
```

Here is the css for the mobile view:

```
@media all and (max-width: 600px) {

/******* Timeline body *******/

.timeline_wrapper{
    max-width: 95%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

.timeline_main_nav {
    display: none;
}

.timeline_body {
    width : 100%;
    float : left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.timeline_ads {
    display: none;
}

.timeline_posts{
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    height: auto;
    border: solid thin #99A6C2;
}





/******* Timeline post body *******/


div.timeline_post_body div.timeline_post_avatar{
    float      :left;
    width      :110px;
    min-height :auto;
    background :#34495E;
    box-sizing: border-box;     
    padding: 10px;
}

div.timeline_post_body div.timeline_post_menu{
    float      :right;
    width      :110px;
    min-height :auto;
    background :#669;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    padding: 10px;  
}

div.timeline_post_body div.timeline_post_title{
    margin     :0 110px 0 110px;
    min-height :auto;
    background :#6BB9F0;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    padding: 10px;  
}

div.timeline_post_body div.timeline_post_body{
    margin     :0 110px 0 110px;
    min-height :auto;
    background :#1E8BC3;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    padding: 10px;  
}

div.timeline_post_body div.timeline_post_footer{
    margin     :0 110px 0 110px;
    min-height :auto;
    background :#4B77BE;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    padding: 10px;  
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a trick of what you are trying to do, use `float: none;` in all `divs` except for `div` **post menu**. And **avatar** should be placed in the bottom of the `div` **post body** so that when you set the **avatar** to `float: none;` it will be position underneath the **post body**. And just a note: Minimize your css like from `div.timeline_post_body div.timeline_post_avatar` to just only `.timeline_post_avatar`. That makes your code so messy. That's very important for future use.